# Crear nuevo objeto a partir de array de objetos

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente array de objetos:

```
const newOb =  [
    {
        "U_Almacen": "014",
        "Estado": "Cerrada",
        "Cantidad": 83,
        "AliasName": "SUC. ALBERDI - (TUCUM\u00c1N)"
    },
    {
        "U_Almacen": "002",
        "Estado": "Abierta",
        "Cantidad": 4,
        "AliasName": "SUC. ALEM - (TUCUM\u00c1N)"
    },
    {
        "U_Almacen": "002",
        "Estado": "Cerrada",
        "Cantidad": 142,
        "AliasName": "SUC. ALEM - (TUCUM\u00c1N)"
    },
    {
        "U_Almacen": "002",
        "Estado": "Desestimada",
        "Cantidad": 1,
        "AliasName": "SUC. ALEM - (TUCUM\u00c1N)"
    }
]
```

Necesito poder agrupar las cantidades que corresponden al mismo U_Almacen de los distintos estados en un nuevo objeto. Me debería quedar de la siguiente forma:

```
[{
   "U_Almacen": "002",
        "AbiertasCantidad": 4,
        "CerradasCantidad": 142,
        "DesestimadasCantidad: 1,
        "AliasName": "SUC. ALEM - (TUCUM\u00c1N)"},
{   "U_Almacen": "014",
        "AbiertasCantidad": 0,
        "CerradasCantidad": 83,
        "DesestimadasCantidad: 0,
        "AliasName": "SUC. ALEM - (TUCUM\u00c1N)"}]
```

Hasta ahora logré separar las cantidades del array de cada objeto pero en diferentes objetos de la siguiente forma:

```
const abiertas = newOb.filter((el) => el.Estado === 'Abierta').map((el) => ({'U_Almacen': el.U_Almacen,'EstadoAbierta': el.Cantidad, 'AliasName': el.AliasName}))

const cerradas = newOb.filter((el) => el.Estado === 'Cerrada').map((el) => ({'U_Almacen': el.U_Almacen,'EstadoCerrado': el.Cantidad, 'AliasName': el.AliasName}))

const desestimadas = newOb.filter((el) => el.Estado === 'Desestimada').map((el)=> ({'U_Almacen': el.U_Almacen,'EstadoDesestimada': el.Cantidad, 'AliasName': el.AliasName}))
```

Pero ahora no se como juntar los resultados de cada uno en un mismo array de objetos renombrando los valores como el ejemplo de más arriba. Alguna idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso lo puedes realizar fácilmente con un `reduce`:

```js
const newOb =  [
    {
        "U_Almacen": "014",
        "Estado": "Cerrada",
        "Cantidad": 83,
        "AliasName": "SUC. ALBERDI - (TUCUM\u00c1N)"
    },
    {
        "U_Almacen": "002",
        "Estado": "Abierta",
        "Cantidad": 4,
        "AliasName": "SUC. ALEM - (TUCUM\u00c1N)"
    },
    {
        "U_Almacen": "002",
        "Estado": "Cerrada",
        "Cantidad": 142,
        "AliasName": "SUC. ALEM - (TUCUM\u00c1N)"
    },
    {
        "U_Almacen": "002",
        "Estado": "Desestimada",
        "Cantidad": 1,
        "AliasName": "SUC. ALEM - (TUCUM\u00c1N)"
    }
]

let resultado = Object.values(newOb.reduce((acc, {U_Almacen, Estado, Cantidad, AliasName}) => {
   acc[U_Almacen] = acc[U_Almacen] || { //Si la clave no existe la creo
      U_Almacen,
      AliasName,
      AbiertasCantidad: 0,
      CerradasCantidad: 0,
      DesestimadasCantidad: 0
   };
   const key = Estado === "Abierta" ? "AbiertasCantidad" : (Estado === "Cerrada" ? "CerradasCantidad" : "DesestimadasCantidad"); //Segun el estado escojo la key
   acc[U_Almacen][key]+=Cantidad; //A esa key le sumo la cantidad
   return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(resultado)
```

Lo que se hace es crear un objeto con clave valor para encontrar el almacen mas rapido y llenar las cantidades. Una vez terminado el `reduce` se cogen solo los valores (usando `Object.values`), es decir, eliminamos las keys del objeto.

Voy a tratar de explicarte como funciona `reduce`.

Reduce lo que hace es iterar sobre todos los elementos de un array y devolviendo "algo", ese algo puede ser lo que tu quieras, puede ser un numero, puede ser un objeto, puede ser un array, puede ser lo que tu quieras, comunmente se le llama acumulador (y por eso en el código lo pongo como `acc`).
`reduce` recibe 2 parámetros, el primero es una funcion (la cual se ejecuta para cada elemento y es responsable de devolver el acumulador), la segunda es el valor inicial del acumulador.

Entonces por ejemplo, si quieres sumar 3 numeros haces:

```js
console.log([1,2,3].reduce((acc, num) => acc+num), 0)
```

Lo que sucede ahí tras bambalinas, es que el acumulador se inicializa en 0.
Luego la funcion se ejecuta con el primer elemento con los siguientes parametros:

(0,1) - Recuerda, el primero el acumulador, el segundo es el elemento del array
Y lo que esa funcion retorna es `acc+num` o sea 0 + 1 = 1

Ahora se procesa lo mismo para el siguiente elemento, ahora para el segundo item el llamado es:
(1,2) --> 1 porque el acumulador ya va en 1, y 2 porque el item  es 2, y devuelve 3

Para el tercer elemento es
(3,3) --> y devuelve 6

Asi de esa misma manera (en la respuesta que te puse) estoy construyendo una estructura similar a esta:

```
{
   "014": {
    "U_Almacen": "014",
    "AliasName": "SUC. ALBERDI - (TUCUMÁN)",
    "AbiertasCantidad": 0,
    "CerradasCantidad": 83,
    "DesestimadasCantidad": 0
  },
  "002": {
    "U_Almacen": "002",
    "AliasName": "SUC. ALEM - (TUCUMÁN)",
    "AbiertasCantidad": 4,
    "CerradasCantidad": 142,
    "DesestimadasCantidad": 1
  }   
}
```

Donde la primera asignacion que usa `acc[U_Almacen]` lo que hago es crear la key del almacen si aun no está creada y la inicializo.
Luego le sumo el valor en la key correspondiente.

Al finalizar todo ese proceso, uso `Object.values` para quitar esos keys del objeto y convertirlo unicamente en un array de valores.

Espero te haya servido.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Estaba seguro que era con un reducer pero no lograba hacerlo. Algún concejo para practicar y terminar de entiender bien el funcionamiento de reducer?

Comment: Te doy una explicación en la misma respuesta, ya te le edito.